# Android SimpleCursorAdapter keep styling on scroll

Tags: java, android, simplecursoradapter

I have a Simple Cursor Adapter which works fine and displays all the data.
My listener changes the color on click:

```
listViewM.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    boolean exists = false;
                    TextView item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.r_lv_name);
                    String selectedAnswer = item.getText().toString();
                    MultiSelection multiSelection = new MultiSelection((int) id, selectedAnswer);

                    for (MultiSelection mm : mMultiSelectionsArray) {
                        if (id == mm.getId()) {
                            mMultiSelectionsArray.remove(mm);
                            exists = true;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            exists = false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!exists) {

                        mMultiSelectionsArray.add(multiSelection);
                        item.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2EFE2E"));
                    } else {

                        mMultiSelectionsArray.remove(multiSelection);
                        item.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                    }

                }
            });
```

Now on scroll adapter is recycling views and marking new items as selected (by adding the color). I guess I need to keep status somehow and then apply it on view creation but after 3 days of looking I give up. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use custom adapter, something like:

```
public class CustomSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        //HERE you can set the correct color for each item

        TextView item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.r_lv_name);
        boolean exists = //check is item is selected
        if (!exists) {
             item.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2EFE2E"));
        } else {
             item.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I already did this but it's the right approach - I tried to check it in main thread instead of Adapter - it's working for me now - Thanks